# How To move container's overflow divs to next container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a book displaying 2 pages at a time.

Each page has 2 columns of text and I want to move the overflow of the columns to the next column without changing the order of the verses.

Current version:
[image: http://imgur.com/AMFLTYN]

and the JS code (using jQuery):

```
$('.column').on('mouseenter mousemove mouseover', function(){


    var column = $(this);
    var feelz = column.find('.feel');
    var columnH = column.height();
    var feelzH = feelz.height();

    var nextcolumn =  $('.column.nextcolumn')
    var column_lastverse = column.find('.feel .verse:last-child');
    var nextcolumn_firstverse = nextcolumn.find('.feel .verse:first-child');

    if (feelzH > columnH)
    {       
        column.addClass('full');
        $('.column.full').next('div.column').addClass('nextcolumn');

        if (column.hasClass('full'))
        {
            column.removeClass('nextcolumn');
            $('.column.full').next('div.column').addClass('nextcolumn'));
        }
        column_lastverse.insertBefore(nextcolumn_firstverse);

    }
    else 
    {
        $(this).removeClass('full');
    }
});
```

The HTML code :

```
        <div><!-- starts 1st page -->
    <div class="top_page"></div>
    <div class="bottom_page"></div>
    <div class="column left"><!--1-->
        <div class="feel">
            <div class="verse">
                <div class="chapter"><span></span> NO princípio criou Deus o céu e a terra.</div></div>
     </div><!-- feelz -->
    </div><!--end column-->
    <div class="column right"><!--1-->
        <div class="feel">
            <div class="verse nospace"></div><!---->
    </div><!-- feelz -->
    </div><!--end column-->
    </div><!-- end page -->
    <div><!-- starts 2nd page-->
    <div class="top_page"></div>
    <div class="bottom_page"></div>        
    <div class="column left">
        <div class="feel">
        <div class="verse nospace"></div>
        </div><!-- feelz -->
    </div><!--end column-->
    <div class="column right"><!--1-->
        <div class="feel">
        <div class="verse nospace"></div>
        </div><!-- feelz -->
    </div><!--end column-->
    </div><!-- end page -->
```

And the CSS code too:

```css
.column 
{
 border-radius:0; 
 height:90%; 
 width:43%;
 top:5%;
 position:absolute;
 overflow-y:visible; 
 padding-left:0; 
 text-align: center; 
 font-size:20px; 
 font-weight: bold;
}
.left
{
 left:5%;
}
.right
{
 right:5%;
}
.feel 
{ 
 width:100%; 
 height:auto; 
 max-height:1000%; 
 min-height:inherit;
 position:absolute; 
 left:0;
}
.verse
{
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: justify;
 font-size: 16px;
 line-height: 20px;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-family:"Arial", Gadget, sans-serif;
}
```

The desired result:
[image: http://imgur.com/5VkrMse]

Any suggestions will be welcome :)

Comment: Please can you provide your HTML as well.

Comment: The html code is on display now :)

Answer (score 1):

there is no need to do this in jquery, you can achieve this using CSS property [columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns).

View this [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/columns/) page.

Use CSS:

```
columns: <column-width> || <column-count>;
```

Example:

```
[Selector]{
    -webkit-columns: 300px 2;
       -moz-columns: 300px 2;
            columns: 300px 2;
}
```

This will do the trick